# Pegar os 2 primeros nomes do usuário

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Digamos que o nome do meu usuário selecionado é "*Raylan Soares Campos*",  como faço para exibir somente os dois primeiros nomes? No caso "*Raylan Soares*".

Estou usando laravel 5.2, não sei se tem algum facilitador  ou se tenho que fazer uma função manualmente, se tiver que fazer podem me dar uma ajuda tbm?

Atualmente estou chamando assim na minha view: `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convém verificar se tem 2 ou mais nomes para o caso de só ter um nome, pegando na solução do Klaider:

```
$names = explode(' ', Auth::user()->name); // Array ( [0] => Raylan [1] => Soares [2] => Campos )
$twoNames = (isset($names[1])) ? $names[0]. ' ' .$names[1] : $names[0];
echo $twoNames; // Raylan Soares
```

Se eu fosse a você enviava isto do controlador.

Comment: Mas no caso dele é necessário ter 2+ nomes. Vai ser desnecessário checar se existe o segundo nome.

Comment: Na verdade não tem um número específico, o usuário poderá realmente ter 1 só ou 2, 5, enfim, acho melhor verificar mesmo, obrigado aos 2

Comment: De nada @RaylanSoares. Ainda bem que ajudei

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar uma coleção para garantir a segurança dos dados sem precisar checar se algo existe antes de chama-lo. Por exemplo:

```
$name = 'Rafael Henrique Berro';

$arr = explode(' ', $name);

$collection = collect($arr);

$firstname = $collection->shift();
$lastname = $collection->shift();

// outputs: Rafael Henrique
```

Você também pode optar por utilizar outros métodos da própria coleção, por exemplo:

```
$name = 'Rafael Henrique Berro';

$arr = explode(' ', $name);

$names = collect($arr)->slice(0, 2)->implode(' ');

// outputs: Rafael Henrique
```

Em uma linha, confuso mas funciona:

```
$names = collect(explode(' ', Auth::user()->name))->slice(0, 2)->implode(' ');
```

Vale a pena conferir os métodos disponíveis e o que é uma coleção na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode partir o nome completo pelos espaços contidos com a função `explode` e depois só juntar os dois primeiros nomes obtidos pelo PHP.

```
/* Separa o nome pelos os espaços na string */
$arr = explode(' ', $fullName);
/* Junta os dois primeiros nomes em uma nova string */
$twoNames = $arr[0] . ' ' . $arr[1];
```

(não precisa checar se tem barra de espaço na string porque já é necessário ter um sobrenome)

Answer (score 0):

Quanto à disponibilização dos dados para a view, sugiro dar uma olhada em [presenters](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) ou [acessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).